# Precise exception

Tags: exception, cpu-architecture, freebsd

I was going through the book The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD operating system and I came across this:

> This ability to restart an instruction is called a precise exception.
>   The CPU may implement restarting by saving enough state when an
>   instruction begins that the state can be restored when a fault is
>   discovered. Alternatively, instructions could delay any modifications
>   or side effects until after any faults would be discovered so that the
>   instruction execution does not need to back up before restarting.

I could not understand what does

> modification or side effects

refer to in the passage. Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

That description from the FreeBSD book is very OS centric. I even disagree with its definition, *This ability to restart an instruction is called a precise exception*. You don't restart an instruction after a power failure exception. So rather than try to figure out what McKusick meant, I'm gonna suggest going elsewhere for a better description of exceptions.

BTW, I prefer Smith's definition:

> An interrupt is precise if the saved process state corresponds with
>   the sequential model of program execution where one instruction completes before the next begins.

https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS316/asset/smith.precise_exceptions.pdf

Almost all modern processors support precise exceptions. So the hard work is already done. What an OS must do is register a trap handler for the exceptions that the hardware takes. For example, there will be a page fault handler, floating point, .... To figure out what is necessary for these handlers you'd have to read the processor theory of operations.

Despite what seems like gritty systems detail, that is fairly high level. It doesn't say anything about what the hardware is doing and so the FreeBSD description is shorthanding a lot.

To really understand *precise exceptions*, you need to read about that in the context of pipelining, out of order, superscalar, ... in a computer architecture book. I'd recommend *Computer Architecture A Quantitative Approach* 6th ed. There's a section *Dealing With Exceptions* p C-38 that presents a taxonomy of the different types of exceptions. The FreeBSD description is only describing some exceptions. It then gets into how each exception type is handled by the pipeline.

Also, *The Linux Programming Interface* has 3 long chapters on the POSIX signal interface. I know it's not FreeBSD but it covers what an application will see when, for example, a floating point exception is taken and a SIGFPE signal is sent to the process.